# newFolderPath=Path.mergePaths(workingDir, newFolderPath) in Hadoop JAr

Tags: java, hadoop

I am going to write to hdfs using hadoop jar. Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class WriteInrix {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
        Path homeDir = hdfs.getHomeDirectory();
        System.out.println("Home folder -" + homeDir);
        Path workingDir = hdfs.getWorkingDirectory();
        System.out.println(workingDir);

        Path newFolderPath = new Path("/MyDataFolder");
        newFolderPath = Path.mergePaths(workingDir, newFolderPath);

        if (hdfs.exists(newFolderPath)) {
            hdfs.delete(newFolderPath, true);
        }

        hdfs.mkdirs(newFolderPath);

        Path localFilePath = new Path("test.csv");
        Path hdfsFilePath = new Path(newFolderPath + "test1.csv");
        hdfs.copyFromLocalFile(localFilePath, hdfsFilePath);
    }
}
```

The problem here is in the line `newFolderPath = Path.mergePaths(workingDir, newFolderPath);`.
This line gives an error as `Path` doesn't have any definition for `mergePaths()`. But I copied the code from a reliable source. What's the problem? What alternative should I use?

Comment: You should provide the actual stacktrace and stdout messages.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see the exact error you are getting. From your code, the only thing that strikes me is should you be doing this instead:

```
Path homeDir = new Path(hdfs.getHomeDirectory());
```

**and**

```
Path workingDir = new Path(hdfs.getWorkingDirectory());
```

**I am just beginning to learn Java/Hadoop so I might be wrong. Please let me know if this works.**

Comment: I m facing the same error but above solution is not working